# Help identifying thread locking adhesive

Tags: adhesives

[image: Grundig TK46, Stereo Tape Recorder, internal view]

I've opened some old electronic device and in many cases, I've come across some adhesive coating the screws, which are in different colors and are easy to break or scratch, I think it's safe to guess they have some sort of thread-locking duties.

For instance, check out this image depicting the internal view of a Grundig TK46 recorder, which by the way I took from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/83637031@N04/8009454909).

So my questions are:

1. What is the specification or part number of these adhesives?
2. What are the alternatives for them in our days? I know the answer is probably is thread-locking fluid, But I want to know if there is any sort of adhesive to be applied to the components and screws and **are similarly easy to break and scratch.**

Comment: It may not be anything fancier than a drop of paint.  Certainly there were (and are) thread locking compounds available, but paint often fit(s) the bill.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a form of lacquer — [nail polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nail_polish) — and is still commonly available today.

A "modern" alternative would be some of the thicker forms of CA ([cyanoacrylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate) — "Super Glue") that wouldn't actually wick down into the the threads, but rather stay on the surface.

Comment: +1 We used automotive touch-up paint for trimpots. Worked fine, and available in lots of different colours for coding etc. and it comes in a convenient package with a brush of appropriate size. The purpose was to indicate that a unit had been calibrated, and to identify cases of "screwdriver drift".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like threadlock. The colours denote the strength. Red is high stength, Green is penetrating. Examples would be loctite 263 for the red and 290 for the green. But for this application it won't be critical unless you're expecting a lot of vibration (eg in a car). As others have said nail polish works fine, but be careful because the solvents in nail polish can be deleterious to things like magnetic heads and rubber belts.